# Adding css class through aspx code behind

Tags: css, class, asp.net, code-behind

I am using aspx.  If I have HTML as follows:

```
<div id="classMe"></div>
```

I am hoping to dynamically add a css class through the code behind file, ie on Page_Load.  Is it possible?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

If you want to add attributes, including the class, you need to set `runat="server"` on the tag.

```
    <div id="classMe" runat="server"></div>
```

Then in the code-behind:

```
classMe.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was sure it would be this simple.

Comment: does this overwrite existing classes?

Comment: @Tyler, no. This adds a new class name to the control. You can also use `Clear` and `Remove` on the `Attributes` collection. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure if i'm missing something, but if you have a class on the initial div (eg. `<div id="classMe" runat="server" class="original"></div>`, the original class declaration is wiped out and you're left with just `class="some-class"` using the code above....seems to contradict @chris-haas's last comment

Comment: if you want to preserve existing classes, you need to do something like: `classMe.Attributes.Add("class", classMe.Attributes["class"] + " some-class"` to not overwrite what you already have

Comment: @DevDave This does override existing classes because you are changing the entire class attribute. This is the same as [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.setAttribute) in javascript. "Adds a new attribute or changes the value of an existing attribute"

Comment: This still works in 2021.  I have the misfortune of working with severely old code but this answer helped me out.

Answer (score 17):

If you're not using the `id` for anything other than code-behind reference (since .net mangles the ids), you could use a `panel` control and reference it in your codebehind:

```
<asp:panel runat="server" id="classMe"></asp:panel>

classMe.cssClass = "someClass"
```

Answer (score 10):

Assuming your *div* has some CSS classes already...

```
<div id="classMe" CssClass="first"></div>
```

The following won't replace existing definitions:

```
ClassMe.CssClass += " second";
```

And if you are not sure until the very last moment...

```
string classes = ClassMe.CssClass;
ClassMe.CssClass += (classes == "") ? "second" : " second";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
controlName.CssClass="CSS Class Name";
```

working example follows below

```
txtBank.CssClass = "csError";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
BtnAdd.CssClass = "BtnCss";
```

BtnCss should be present in your Css File.

(reference of that Css File name should be added to the aspx if needed)

Answer (score 2):

Syntax:

```
controlName.CssClass="CSS Class Name";
```

Example:

```
txtBank.CssClass = "csError";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain the existing class, this would work:

```
string existingClass = classMe.Attributes["class"];
classMe.CssClass = existingClass + " some-class";
```