# Problem adding attributes to Asp ListBox's ListItems in code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

My ListBox on aspx page is as follows:-

```
 <asp:ListBox ID="ddlItems" runat="server" Style="padding: 2px; width: 210px; height:200px;">
  </asp:ListBox>
```

I am adding BackGround Image to my List items as

follows in code behind and its working perfectly:-

```
myListItem.Attributes.Add("style", "background-image:url(" + "'www.mysite.com/"  + 

"images/Gradient/" + ds.Tables[0].Rows[iGroups]

["Backgroundimage"].ToString() + "');");
```

Now I have tried many things but I cant get to make

the list items' font bold and White in color. Also

how can I increase the height of these list items

and hence the font size?

I have tried the following but its' not working:-

```
  myListItem.Attributes.Add("ForeColor", "White");
  myListItem.Attributes.Add("style", "font-weight:bold");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use CssClass property or set 'class' attribute instead of style, because if you're setting multiple styles, you are in fact overwriting style each time.

CssClass:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx

setting class in code behind:
[Adding css class through aspx code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903513/adding-css-class-through-aspx-code-behind)