# Add cssstyle in code-behind with Attributes

Tags: asp.net, css, code-behind

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding css class through aspx code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903513/adding-css-class-through-aspx-code-behind)

Im trying to assign a css-class to button created in a overridden CreateChildControls-method like this:

```
HtmlButton btn = new HtmlButton();
btn.ServerClick += new EventHandler(resultSelected);
btn.InnerText = "btn text";
btn.Attributes.CssStyle.Remove("class");
btn.Attributes.CssStyle.Add("class", "submitbutton");
this.Controls.Add(btn);
PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

But I guess I need to specify my stylesheet-file for it to work...I want to use the same one as in the aspx.

Comment: Have a look [Adding css class through aspx code behind](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903513/adding-css-class-through-aspx-code-behind)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Following code will work,

```
btn.Attributes["class"]= "submitbutton";
```

OR

```
btn.CssClass="submitbutton";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `CssStyle`

```
btn.Attributes.Remove("class");
btn.Attributes.Add("class", "submitbutton");
```

Or

```
btn.CssClass="submitbutton";
```

Comment: Removing CssStyle didnt work for me.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the CssStyle property incorrectly. This property expects you to provide CSS name value pairs. What you want to do is [add an Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.add.aspx) with name "class".

```
btn.Attributes.Add("class", "submitbutton");
```

Have a look at the MSDN for [CssStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.attributecollection.cssstyle.aspx) property. It is what is rendered into the inline style attribute.