# Add CSS ID code behind

Tags: c#, css, code-behind

I want to add my own ID in code behind without declaring it in the front code. Is it possible?

To clarify my question, here is an example : 
[Adding css class through aspx code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903513/adding-css-class-through-aspx-code-behind][1])

In front code:

```
<div id="classMe" runat="server"></div>
```

In code behind:

```
classMe.Attributes.Add("class", "some-class")
```

Is it possible to set my own ID, the id="classMe" in code behind?

Something like:

```
WebForm.Css.ID.Add         = "classMe";
WebForm.Css.Attributes.Add = "background-color:red";
```

Comment: Hi Sir @Pete , first of all thank you for your response. I am using ext.net v1. and I will be using it to change the color of the calendar day in calendarpanel. the IDs I will be using for css will come from the database. for example : `#CalendarPanel1-month-day-20120220 {
    background-color: Red;
}`    The 20120220 is from the database